# activation code in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, activation-codes

when a user asks for forgot password , i send an activation email which works okay. but when the user activated the code and created the new password, if the user try to access the activation code for  second it should say the activation code is failed/Invalid. how to check the clicks on the activation code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could delete the activation code from your database, once it has been used successfully? (or generate a new one "for next time")

Comment: can you explain me, how to delete the activation code from database once its been used?

Comment: It all depends on your table schema, and *how* you connect to the database, but Pseudo-code would loosely be: Validate code is valid; Update, set activation code to be null (or a different one), also set password to be new value at the same time

Comment: i think rather than deleting the activation code i just want to remove or make it null(in the code itself) and i don't want to touch the database

Comment: The only way of using an activation code once, is to store that it's been used, or otherwise make it invalid. sure you can do that in code, but you're going to have to store that somewhere, and it would be sensible to store it in the database, alongside the rest of the data (heck, it'll be a lot easier if you ever need to restore from backups)

Answer (score 0):

Have a flag in the database that marks it as invalid.